# Xamrain Forms Maps not working as expected

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget

I am trying to use the Xamrin forms map inteface to add custom pins acording to the doumenation here on microsoft but I am having an error it said that it should add the google play services automatically but it does not so I am trying to use the nuget.

Microsoft documentaiton

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map

Nuget for google play sevices

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps/

But I also get the following error.

> GET https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
>   Install-Package : Failed to retrieve information about 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps' from remote source 
>   'https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
>     An error occurred while sending the request.
>     Unable to connect to the remote server
>     An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps -Version 71.1610.0
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Strange thing is this i have it set to nuget.org

[image]

Comment: check your nuget sources.  It is trying to load from telerik's NuGet repo, not nuget.org

Comment: @Jason i have telerik installed as well thanks for that though must be trying to go to it first.

Comment: @Jason please see above i think ur right but its set to default as nuget.og

Comment: @rogue39nin Froms this error , you can check the network first .And second do you use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps/71.1610.0) Nuget Package ?